# How many comparisons required by following algorithms to arrange the A array in decreasingorder? Insertion sort, Quick sort, Selection sort, Heap Sort

Tags: quicksort, insertion-sort, heapsort

Suppose you are given an array A of 'n' integers in increasing order. How many comparisons required by the following algorithms to arrange the A array in decreasing order? Insertion sort, Quick sort, Selection sort, Heap Sort.

I was just thinking that insertion sort can not be done because it arranges the elements in increase order.

HELP ME SENPAI:-(

Comment: Why not just write a program that does it and counts the number of comparisons?

Comment: "*insertion sort can not be done because it arranges the elements in increase order*" that depends on where you insert your elements

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.